# spring http-basic

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

may i know can we specify url for http-basic so that only authenticate if go to particular page? example login.jsp ? i do not want to use form login.

Comment: can you elaborate your question? are you asking on authentication you wanted to go to some page? and you dont want to use form login

Comment: i'm using spring  <security:http-basic />   any specific url parameter i can set with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring approach:

```
<security:http>
    <security:http-basic></security:http-basic>
    <security:intercept-url method="POST" pattern="/mypage.jsp" access="ROLE_USER" />
</security:http>
```

As you see, at the **intercept-url** element you can define the resources under access control. It has an attribute ***pattern*** where you can define the url pattern (admiting wildcards) of such resources.

Comment: is it possible to define  url=login.jsp do formlogin;  url=login2.jsp , do http-basic login ?

Comment: Yes, from Spring Security 3.1 you can add the "pattern" attribute to the http element, and this configuration will just apply to the matching urls

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by configuration of your web application, whether you are using spring or not.

[Configuring Security in Web Applications](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs70/webapp/security.html)

The resources on wich you are going to apply the security constraint are specified at the "security-constrant" element of the `web.xml` deployment descriptor. By example:

```
<security-constraint>
     <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>SecureOrdersEast</web-resource-name>
          <description>
             Security constraint for
             resources in the orders/east directory
          </description>
          <url-pattern>/orders/east/*</url-pattern>
          <http-method>POST</http-method>
          <http-method>GET</http-method>
     </web-resource-collection>
     <auth-constraint>
          <description>
           constraint for east coast sales
          </description>
          <role-name>east</role-name>
          <role-name>manager</role-name>
     </auth-constraint>
     <user-data-constraint>
          <description>SSL not required</description>
          <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
     </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

And, to define the Auth method as BASIC, you have to define it also at the `web.xml` file, in a login-config element:

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

At the login-config you can also define the login realm, and other options. You can find more information at [web.xml Deployment Descriptor Elements: login-config](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1019996).

Comment: no i want to use spring approach which is <security:http-basic />

Comment: @cometta: sorry, it wasn't very clear at the original question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `<security:http-basic>`, you could define your own filters and use appropriately.  For instance

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/login.jsp"        filters="formExceptionTranslationFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/login2.jsp"        filters="basicProcessingFilter"/>
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```